# Static discharge inside a fuel tank

Tags: mechanical-engineering, experimental-physics

I am trying to build a sort of paramotor powered by hydrogen, my rough design looks like this;

[image: https://ibb.co/wdYnqcV]

First dilute sulfuric acid is electrolyzed in a sealed aluminium container.

Second, the valve is manually opened to let the pressurized HHO gas flow and is then ignited in the pipe.

Propeller is attached to the tesla turbine which rotates it high RPM.

The residual distilled water is collected then transferred back into the container forming dilute h2so4 again.

Now the reason I chose a tesla turbine is because it operates at very high RPM and has very high power density and efficiency.

And the reason why I just don’t buy a paramotor is because;

1, Hydrogen is a relatively clean fuel and doesn’t produce any co2.

2. Energy density is 10MJ/kg which is 10 times better than any battery therefore not buying a electric paramotor.

My concern is when i would be using this thing, could electrostatic charges develop and cause a spark inside the container?

Comment: what you are building if you do not segregate the oxygen and hydrogen from the electrolysis is a bomb.  Yes, there is a huge risk.  I recommend you focus on one thing at a time, like how to safely electrolyze water, or how to make a Tesla turbine feasible (for example, what are you doing to do with this high rpm output?).  This is a lot of steps to turn electricity into motion.

Answer (score 0):

In an electrochemical cell, you are not electrolyzing sulfuric acid, you are electrolyzing water molecules. Electrolyzing water requires the flow of electric current through the cell. Your diagram has no electrical power supply connected to the carbon electrodes, so it will not work.